# How to interrupt a H4 text if too long

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a title in `<H4>` text inside a `<header>` tag in wordpress. I want that if the title is too long (does not fit inside the `<header>` width) the text is truncated and "..." added in its place.

So for example the title (taken from ipsum generator):

> Audiam tritani prompta mel ex

Should look like:

> Audiam tritani promp...

Tried to play with the overflow property with no success..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem a while ago. You can simple add `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to the styling of the `h4` tag.

Have you looked at W3 Schools solution? Check it out at this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp).

Your final code should look something like this:

```css
#div1 {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 12em; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: clip; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

#div2 {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 12em; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- THIS Code was taken from W3 Schools-->
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>

<p>The following two divs contains a long text that will not fit in the box. As you can see, the text is clipped.</p>

<p>This div uses "text-overflow:clip":</p>
<div id="div1">This is some long text that will not fit in the box</div>

<p>This div uses "text-overflow:ellipsis":</p>
<div id="div2">This is some long text that will not fit in the box</div>
  <h1>Code from W3 Schools!</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hello, worked for me by adding this part only to the relevant H4:

`    .home-top-sidebar .entry-title {
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap; 
    }`

Comment: Happy I helped ;)

Comment: what if I want to fill in 2 lines then truncate with ellipsis instead?

Comment: I don't understand. Could you maybe show me how you want it to look in an image or be a bit more descriptive?

Comment: I mean that given the parent size the <H4> element should extend for 2 lines and add ellipses only to the second line and not at the first.

Comment: Just add a `<div>` tag around the second line and give it the styling property to `text-overflow: ellipsis;`

Comment: I dont know if there would be a second line nor where it starts, its content generated from Wordpress..

Answer (score 3):

By using `text-overflow: ellipsis`

```
h4 {
    width: /** your width **/
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Using these will cut-off your long text based on your width and adds a `...` on it.

Here's a live code from W3Schools:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #div1 {
      white-space: nowrap;
      width: 12em;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: clip;
      border: 1px solid #000000;
    }
    #div2 {
      white-space: nowrap;
      width: 12em;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      border: 1px solid #000000;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <p>The following two divs contains a long text that will not fit in the box. As you can see, the text is clipped.</p>

  <p>This div uses "text-overflow:clip":</p>
  <div id="div1">This is some long text that will not fit in the box</div>

  <p>This div uses "text-overflow:ellipsis":</p>
  <div id="div2">This is some long text that will not fit in the box</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Look more in [W3Schools: text-overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp).

Comment: I believe it supports FF 7.0+ as stated in W3Schools.

Comment: Use `white-space:nowrap;` instead of `word-wrap` https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/t0mdr5L2/1/

Comment: Oh thanks, I forgot. Bit confused with the word "wrap". :v